# Error Log for SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am importing some data through SSIS , in case some records don't get pushed , I am writing those errors in a .txt file :

E.g

Data Push failed for abcColumn: 8702170000,The data value violates integrity constraints.

But when the column 'abcColumn' is blank

it is just showing

,The data value violates integrity constraints.

Can't I show it as:

Data pushed for abcColumn : blank/null/_(space) ,The data value violates integrity constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to implement custom error handling mechanism in your packages so that you can get error message of your choice.

Below are the few resources which can be served as starting point.

- [Capturing and Logging Data Load Errors for an SSIS Package](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2149/capturing-and-logging-data-load-errors-for-an-ssis-package/)
- [Custom Logging Using Event Handlers](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/06/11/SSIS_3A00_-Custom-Logging-Using-Event-Handlers.aspx)
- [Custom Messages for Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345174.aspx)
- [SSIS Design Pattern - Custom Error Handling](http://vsteamsystemcentral.com/cs21/blogs/applied_business_intelligence/archive/2007/04/08/ssis-design-pattern-custom-error-handling.aspx)
- [SSIS Script Task – Custom Error Messages](http://themonitoringguy.com/tips-tricks/ssis-script-task-custom-error-messages/)

Comment: Okay , thanks, I'll go through the links, But is there a property of SSIS that if the column name is empty (which I am using in my error description) , it doesn't write the error.