# SSIS Log not sequential order

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have enabled the SSIS logging for my package on the following events :

- OnError
- OnPreExecute
- OnPostExecute
- OnPostValidate
- On Warning

The logs are created however the sort order is incorrect, the package start row is in the middle of the logs, ex :

```
id  | event        | source        | starttime               | endtime                 | message
1   | OnWarning    | MyTaskName    | 2015-08-19 18:50:36.000   2015-08-19 18:50:36.000 | Truncation may occur 
-- Other logs
10  | PackageStart | MyPackageName | 2015-08-19 18:50:36.000   2015-08-19 18:50:36.000 | Start of the execution of the package
```

The start time and the end time is the same for most of the logs which make it almost impossible to use it for order by and the id does not seem to be sequential !

Do you know any other way to get it sorted properly ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a custom error file. See
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610018/error-log-for-ssis)